# Is it possible to render a value from an input on my page on someone else's page?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, input

Is it possible to from an input on my page (a simple page that i've created), place it on someone else's page input?

For example on my page I've a input to someone write their name, and then when they press submit, the value that they inserted appears on another page input field? Is this possible without have to rewrite the code of the destination page.

Comment: If you can specify both sites here, someone may be able to give you an opinion. As Quentin says, this may be possible via the query string, but we'd just be guessing.

Answer (score 2):

No.

It is impossible for site A to direct a user's browser to site B while modifying site B.

Either site B needs to provide a mechanism for allowing the input to be preset (such as through the query string) or you need to proxy site B so that (as far as the browser is concerned) it is part of site A (which you can control, so you can modify the HTML as it passes through your server).

Comment: Thank you! ;) It was a question that i had for a long time. Thank you again for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

No, if you don't control the destination page, it is definitely not possible.

Comment: Thank you! ;) It was a question that i had for a long time. Thank you again for your answer!